# How to set password for keycloak users?

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-rest-api

How do I set a password for a user within a realm? I've tried

```
$ kcadm.sh update users/$user_id/reset-password -r My-Realm -s type=password -s value=NEWPWD -s temporary=false -n
```

and

```
$ kcadm.sh set-password -r My-Realm --username user1 --new-password NEWPASSWORD
```

and when I log in to Keycloak and check the user - no password has been set. Am I missing something here?

The last option (which would make my script look ugly) is using the `/auth/admin/realms/$realm/users` API

Please help. This is something very trivial but I've already spent a day trying to achieve it :(

Comment: So your user, is already created but you want to set it with a new password right? I have tested your command ./kcadm.sh set-password -r test --username user1 --new-password NEWPASSWORD and with Keycloak 15.1 is working fine which version do you have

Answer (score 2):

this is how i'm setting up a test user

```bash
# authentificate with admin credentials
$ kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://localhost:8080 --realm master --user admin

# create user
$ kcadm.sh create users -s username=test -s email=test@example.com -s enabled=true -s emailVerified=true -r demo

# set password
$ kcadm.sh set-password -r demo --username test --new-password 111111
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PUT method for change reset password API.
[image]

You can see this event from Keycloak UI after turn on "Admin Events Settings"
[image]

Comment: when you log in to the console and click on the user, can you view their credentials?

Comment: The log did not print this change in the console but  If you turn on the "admin events settings" in realm's Event/Config UI of Keycloak, you can see this event with "Action" of Operation Type, "USER" of Resource type and user ID/reset-password log with time stamp.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem yesterday. When the password is written in capital case (haven't tried a password with a few upper cases), then there was no password set for the user.

Easy solution was to write the whole password in lower case, numbers and special chars are fine.

```bash
# user won't get a password
$ kcadm.sh set-password -r My-Realm --username user1 --new-password NEWPASSWORD

# works
$ kcadm.sh set-password -r My-Realm --username user1 --new-password newpassword
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, in Keycloak 20.0.3, it works this way:

```
./kcadm.sh config credentials --server http://127.0.0.1:8080/auth --realm master --user adminuser --password adminuserpass --config config.properties
KEYCLOAK_USERNAME="testuser"
KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD="TestPass123!$%"
./kcadm.sh set-password -r testrealm --username $KEYCLOAK_USERNAME --new-password $KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD --config config.properties
```