# forgot password button in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak, forgot-password, reset-password

I use Keycloak as an access management and authentication system
I implemented the admin panel of my site with React and I want to add a forgot password button and a password reset feature for the users of my site.
Which Keycloak API should I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call reset password API

```
PUT /{realm}/users/{id}/reset-password
```

[image]

In [Keycloak Admin REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/18.0/rest-api/) at `Set up a new password for the user` section.

[How to set password for keycloak users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72578854/how-to-set-password-for-keycloak-users/72579057#72579057)